# Copy directory and files from java project resource

Tags: java, file-io, resources

I need to copy the directory "src" that is located in my java project, as a common resource. This "src" folder contains other subfolders and files, so I need them to be copied as well. How can I achieve something like this??
The main problem I'm facing is that I can't retrieve the absolute path of my "src" folder.
A solution would be to copy file by file but their are too much and I would like to find a better solution

Thank you

EDIT:
When the user click on "Generate" button, my app ask to the user a target location where to generate some files. This target location is where I want to copy my "src" folder with all its children. The "src" folder, as sad above, is located in my java project main folder.

Comment: How you try to copy them? If you have some recource files in `src` and you use maven then you should create a `resource` directory for those files (`src/main/resources`). Maven will handle them for you.

Comment: I am not using Maven,but maybe I didn't explained my problem enough...look at the EDIT

Comment: So you only need to find the directory containing your application? You could try `YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this could be a good way to do it, but it throws me a FileNotFoundException: The syntax of the file name, directory or volume is wrong...

Comment: The folder I have to copym, is a template of a Java application, maybe I could put the JAR archive of this app in my resource folder and instead of copying the src folder with all its children, I could copy just the JAR file...Then I should open the JAR file because after the copy action I need to add some code to a class of the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem creating a zip archive of the app I need to generate. Then from my project I unzip this archive taken from resource folder and after that I open the stream of the java file I need to modify and I edit it.
This is the code, similar to SubOptimal's solution

```
UnzipUtility unzipper = new UnzipUtility();
InputStream inputStream = getClass()
        .getResource("/template/template.zip").openConnection()
        .getInputStream();
unzipper.unzip(inputStream, parentFolder.getCanonicalPath());
```

The UnzipUtility class is from this example: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/programmatically-extract-a-zip-file-using-java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the sources from a jar file you could start with this short example

```
public class UnZip {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        String destDir = "/tmp/";
        String sourceJar = "your_src.jar";

        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceJar)))) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                File newDestination = new File(destDir + zipEntry.getName());
                if (zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    unzipDir(newDestination);
                } else {
                    unzipFile(newDestination, zis);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("input file coud not be read " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void unzipFile(File file, final ZipInputStream zis) {
        System.out.printf("extract to: %s - ", file.getAbsoluteFile());
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("already exist");
            return;
        }
        int count;
        try (BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
            while ((count = zis.read(BUFFER, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                dest.write(BUFFER, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("file could not be created " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void unzipDir(File dir) {
        System.out.printf("create directory: %s - ", dir);
        if (dir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("already exist");
        } else if (dir.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
    }

    static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    static byte[] BUFFER = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
}
```